# Cannot Access Closed Stream

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, caching-application-block

I'm trying to use the [Caching Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480453.aspx) to cache some images (these images take a long time to render)

```
  BitmapSource bitmapSource; ///some bitmap source already created
  _cache ///  Caching Application Block
  String someId; //id for this image, used as the key for the cache

  using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Interlace = PngInterlaceOption.On;
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource));             
        encoder.Save(stream);
        _cache.Add(someId, stream);
    }
```

And then load them using:

```
imStream = (Stream)_cache.GetData(someId));
if (imStream != null)
{
    PngBitmapDecoder decoder = new PngBitmapDecoder(imStream,  BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
    return decoder.Frames[0];  //return the bitmap source
}
```

But during the load, i get the following exception at that "new PngBitmapDecoder" line:

> "Cannot access a closed Stream.

I understand I closed the stream in the above code, but isn't _cache.Add() making a copy (via Serialization) before it exits?  What's the correct process of serializing the stream?

THanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> but isn't _cache.Add() making a copy (via Serialization) before it exits?

Not necessarily. If it is "in process" it will just store the object reference; `Stream` isn't really very serializable anyway (a `Stream` is a hose, not a bucket).

You want to store the BLOB - not the `Stream`:

```
    _cache.Add(someId, stream.ToArray());

...

byte[] blob = _cache.GetData(someId);
if(blob != null) {
    using(Stream inStream = new MemoryStream(blob)) {
         // (read)
    } 
}
```

Comment: thanks! both good answers, i just marked the one that came first :)

i like the host/bucket reference.

Comment: @moogs - actually this one came in first (04:55:29 vs 04:46:05).

Comment: that was weird... the "answered xx mins ago" was higher for this post earlier. hmm.

Comment: I assure you that even with ♦ I can't change that.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that the stream is closed (via `Dispose()`) at the end of the `using` block. You retain a reference to the closed stream.

Instead, save the contents of the stream to your cache:

```
_cache.Add(someId, stream.ToArray());
```

When you call the `PngBitmapDecoder` constructor, you'll have to create a new `MemoryStream` to read from that byte array.