# Cannot access a closed Stream while creating a downloadable text file in ASP MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to prompt a downloadable text file (.txt), but I get this error:

> Cannot access a closed Stream.

I have looked at simular questions in here:
[Cannot Access Closed Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331675/cannot-access-closed-stream)
But it was not very useful.

Here is my code:

```
    private FileStreamResult Export()
    {
        string name = "filename.txt";

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("A text...");
            writer.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        }

        return File(stream, "text/plain", name);
    }
```

**UPDATE (working copy):**

This gives me an blank text file.

```
private FileResult Export()
{
    string name = "filename.txt";

    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("A text...");
    writer.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

    writer.Flush();
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    return File(stream, "text/plain", name);
}
```

Comment: which line you get this error ?!!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

That is correct, when you wrap a stream in another stream, calling `.Close()` or `.Dispose()` on any of them will dispose the whole stream. In this case, wrapping the `MemoryStream` in a `StreamWriter` means that when the `using` statement completes the `StreamWriter` and `MemoryStream` are both disposed.

My guess is since you are returning a `FileStreamResult` the encapsulating `File` will close the stream for you after the stream is no longer used. In this case, you do not want to use the `using` statement and will want to leave the stream open when returning it.

**UPDATE**

Since a stream is forward access you'll need to see the stream back to the beginning to allow the data to be read back out.

```
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

Comment: Thanks, see my reply to #archil.

Comment: Since it's a memory stream you may need to [Seek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.seek.aspx) to the beginning of the stream. See my update. You're getting zero bytes because there is no data at the current position of the stream, at the end. :)

Answer (score 13):

Just remove that `using` statement - you are passing disposed object reference to `File` method and you that's the reason why you get exception. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtbhzte9.aspx#Y700),

> The StreamWriter object calls Dispose on the provided Stream object
>   when StreamWriter.Dispose is called.

I believe `File` will dispose stream by itself after usage (not verified by looking at source code).

**UPDATE:**

`writer.Flush();` before return statement should help you

Comment: Thank you both #archil and #Joshua. I tried to remove the using, but now I get a empty text file. What did I do wrong? I have updated my question with the new code.

Comment: I wish for it to work, but the txt file is still at 0 byte. And I see that the stream have positive length, so it has to be something there. Strange..

Answer (score 5):

You have to set the position of the memorystream to 0 before using it in your FileStreamResult, otherwise it will be read from current position (IE the end of the stream).

```
stream.Position = 0;
return File(stream, "text/plain", name);
```

Just had the same thing.

I know this thread is ancient, just hoping to aid others having the same issue.

Comment: It's always the little things. I was getting an empty file but it was the correct "lenght".. the position was the fix. seems to me but when creating a new FileStreamResult from a MemoryStream, it should know better.

Comment: I agree (somewhat) - Overloads for known stream-types (which support setting position) would be helpful for most cases, though it smells like a leaky abstraction to me.

Comment: I think a simple 'Input-Stream is read from it's current position and forwards'-note in the summary of it's ctor would go a long way...

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `FileStreamResult` type on your action with `FileResult`.