# Cannot access closed stream thrown depending on Visual Studio version

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, stream

I have an interesting scenario with writing and reading data from streams in .NET 4. This behaviour first showed up when I switched from Visual Studio 2012 to 2013. *Keep that last sentence in mind, as it's the main reason for this question*. It feels like the version of VS should *not* affect this behaviour in any way whatsoever, since i'm still compiling against the same framework version.

The scenario I have is that i'm running ASP.NET WebForms and we're customizing the output of a specific ASP.NET control being rendered. *Actually, it's a third-party control that we have an inheritence relationship with, where we customize the output from the control.*

Here is the code in where the error happens (I slightly modified the source code in an attempt to better show you my points):

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
{
    using (var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            var htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(writer);
            base.Render(htmlWriter);
            htmlWriter.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;

            using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
            {
                string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                // modify content...
                output.Write(content);
                reader.Close();
            }
        } // exception thrown
    }
}
```

Here's the exception message:

> Cannot access a closed Stream.

I *do* understand that the exception itself is being thrown, as is explained here: [MemoryStream - Cannot access a closed Stream.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934585/memorystream-cannot-access-a-closed-stream) In fact *i'm very curious to know why this code have been working for such a long time*. It's clearly pointed out by a number of different answers here on stackoverflow that this is not the proper way to handle streams. [Here's another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152586/cannot-access-a-closed-stream-while-creating-a-downloadable-text-file-in-asp-mvc).

If I compile this exact same code in Visual Studio 2012, it all "works", i.e. I do not get the exception. However, when compiling in VS 2013 I do get the exception.

If you've read this far you might also want to know my environment setup. These are the points I think might be worth for you to know in order to give any guidance.

- WebSite project
- Hosted locally in IIS 7.5
- Targets .NET 4.0
- Built in Debug mode using Any CPU

The actual question: **How can the version of Visual Studio affect this behaviour?**

**Update1:** Settings under Exceptions -> Common Language Runtime exceptions is set to 'User-unhandled' for both VS2012/13. 'Thrown' is unchecked.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have the Exceptions -> Common Language Runtime Exceptions filter checked on in VS2013? Perhaps it's always been thrown.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I was thinking the same but I double-checked those settings and they are the same. I'll update this and add to the question.

Comment: This is still something where I never figured out the real problem. I did have another problem as well with the StreamWriter class when trying to save data to a new text file. I still have the feeling that the StreamWriter class have changed behaviour (which sounds very strange).