# MemoryStream - Cannot access a closed Stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, streamwriter, memorystream

Why  `using (var sw = new StreamWriter(ms))` returns `Cannot access a closed Stream` `exception` while the `MemoryStream` is on top of this code?

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(ms))
    {                 
        sw.WriteLine("data");
        sw.WriteLine("data 2");
        ms.Position = 0;
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(ms))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());                        
        }
    } //error here
}
```

Comment: This may be because you are creating a StreamWriter and StreamReader from the same MemoryStream.  You might try using two different MemoryStreams: one for reader and one for writer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331675/cannot-access-closed-stream

Comment: In some situations a solution can be based on creating a new `MemoryStream` based on using `MemoryStream.GetBuffer()` on the closed memory stream. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50671919/253938

Answer (score 150, accepted):

This is because the `StreamReader` closes the underlying stream automatically when being disposed of. The `using` statement does this automatically.

However, the `StreamWriter` you're using is still trying to work on the stream (also, the `using` statement for the writer is now trying to dispose of the `StreamWriter`, which is then trying to close the stream).

The best way to fix this is: don't use `using` and don't dispose of the `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862261/can-you-keep-a-streamreader-from-disposing-the-underlying-stream).

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    var sw = new StreamWriter(ms);
    var sr = new StreamReader(ms);

    sw.WriteLine("data");
    sw.WriteLine("data 2");
    ms.Position = 0;

    Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());                        
}
```

If you feel bad about `sw` and `sr` being garbage-collected without being disposed of in your code (as recommended), you could do something like that:

```
StreamWriter sw = null;
StreamReader sr = null;

try
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        sw = new StreamWriter(ms);
        sr = new StreamReader(ms);

        sw.WriteLine("data");
        sw.WriteLine("data 2");
        ms.Position = 0;

        Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());                        
    }
}
finally
{
    if (sw != null) sw.Dispose();
    if (sr != null) sr.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: There's little doubt there which I'm assuming why OP asked "What the best way to fix it ?"

Comment: What about close var sw = new StreamWriter(ms);
    var sr = new StreamReader(ms); ?

Comment: You don't need to worry about them. I quote the accepted answer from the question I linked: *You should be OK by leaving the StreamReader go out of scope if you need to use the underlying stream directly. Just make sure you dispose the underlying stream manually when it's appropriate.* In other words: while the reader and writer are not disposed of explicitly, they will be garbage collected in the end. But I'll edit again to give another possible solution.

Comment: This code did not work for me. https://dotnetfiddle.net/UTBDAh, in compare to `leaveOpen` answer that did work. Or need `.Flush()` https://dotnetfiddle.net/69fBxR

Answer (score 45):

Since .net45 you can use the `LeaveOpen` constructor argument of `StreamWriter` and still use the `using` statement. Example:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(ms, leaveOpen:true))
    {
        sw.WriteLine("data");
        sw.WriteLine("data 2");    
    }

    ms.Position = 0;
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(ms))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning, can also be used without "using"-Statement. (my underlying MemoryStream needs to stay alive) and -1 to Microsoft for forcing me into **that** ugly ctor. ^^

Comment: @Jan you could use `new StreamWriter(ms, leaveOpen:true)` which i guess is a bit less ugly

Comment: this code works. https://dotnetfiddle.net/jTYGak

Answer (score 9):

When the `using()` for your `StreamReader` is ending, it's disposing the object and closing the stream, which your `StreamWriter` is still trying to use.

Comment: There's little doubt there which I'm assuming why OP asked "What the best way to fix it ?"

Answer (score 2):

when it gets out from the using statement the `Dispose` method will be called automatically closing the stream

try the below:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    var sw = new StreamWriter(ms);

        sw.WriteLine("data");
        sw.WriteLine("data 2");
        ms.Position = 0;
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(ms))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this block:

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(ms))
{
    Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());                        
}
```

When the `StreamReader` is closed (after leaving the using), it closes it's underlying stream as well, so now the `MemoryStream` is closed. When the `StreamWriter` gets closed, it tries to flush everything to the `MemoryStream`, but it is closed.

You should consider not putting the `StreamReader` in a using block.

Answer (score 1):

You have to leave the stream open to be able to read it.
the "StreamWriter" closes it after it is done writing

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(ms, leaveOpen: true)))
    {                 
        sw.WriteLine("data");
        sw.WriteLine("data 2");
        ms.Position = 0;
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(ms))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());                        
        }
    } //error here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case (admittedly very arcane and not likely to be reproduced often), this was causing the problem (this code is related to PDF generation using iTextSharp):

```
PdfPTable tblDuckbilledPlatypi = new PdfPTable(3);
float[] DuckbilledPlatypiRowWidths = new float[] { 42f, 76f };
tblDuckbilledPlatypi.SetWidths(DuckbilledPlatypiRowWidths);
```

The declaration of a 3-celled/columned table, and then setting only two vals for the width was what caused the problem, apparently. Once I changed "PdfPTable(3)" to "PdfPTable(2)" the problem went the way of the convection oven.

Comment: This should be another question + answer. It has nothing to do with OP problem. While it may be very useful to `iTextSharp` users the way you provide help to others is wrong (putting it into random question with only similar exception text?)