# Why am I getting "Cannot access a closed Stream" here?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, itext

Stack trace looks like

> [ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.]
>   System.IO.__Error.StreamIsClosed() +53
>   System.IO.MemoryStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>   +11411219    System.Web.Mvc.FileStreamResult.WriteFile(HttpResponseBase response)
>   +81    System.Web.Mvc.FileResult.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +168
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13

after invoking

```
        //Byte[] bytes;
        using ( var ms = new MemoryStream() )
        {
            using ( var doc = new Document() )
            {
                using ( var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms) )
                {

                    doc.Open();
                    //var example_html = @"<p>This <em>is </em><span class=""headline"" style=""text-decoration: underline;"">some</span> <strong>sample <em> text</em></strong><span style=""color: red;"">!!!</span></p>";
                    var example_html = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/EmailTemplates"), "template.html"));
                    var example_css = @".headline{font-size:200%}";
                    using ( var srHtml = new StringReader(example_html) )
                    {
                        iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, srHtml);
                    }
                    using ( var msCss = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(example_css)) )
                    {
                        using (var msHtml = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(example_html)))
                        {
                            iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, msHtml, msCss);
                        }
                    }


                    doc.Close();
                }
            }
            //bytes = ms.ToArray();
            return File(ms, "application/pdf", "Test.pdf");
        }
```

I've read [MemoryStream - Cannot access a closed Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934585/memorystream-cannot-access-a-closed-stream), but that's not the same scenario because I'm not using `StreamReader`

**Edit:** Still not working with

```
    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
    public ActionResult Run()
    {
        Byte[] bytes;
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        try
        {
            using (var doc = new Document())
            {
                using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms))
                {
                    writer.CloseStream = false;
                    doc.Open();
                    var example_html = @"<p>This <em>is </em><span class=""headline"" style=""text-decoration: underline;"">some</span> <strong>sample <em> text</em></strong><span style=""color: red;"">!!!</span></p>";
                    //var example_html = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/EmailTemplates"), "LinkEmailTemplate.html"));
                    var example_css = @".headline{font-size:200%}";
                    using (var msCss = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(example_css)))
                    {
                        using (var msHtml = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(example_html)))
                        {
                            iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, msHtml, msCss);
                        }
                    }
                    doc.Close();
                }
            }
            bytes = ms.ToArray();
            ms.Position = 0;
            return File(ms, "application/pdf", "Test.pdf");
        }
        catch
        {
            ms.Dispose();
            throw;
        }           
    }
```

Comment: Because the stream was closed as soon as you exited the action method. When the view tried to access it, it found it was already closed.

Comment: `Still not working with` - define `not working`. Also you have a variable named `bytes` which does not do anything but I am curious if there is anything in this array before your method exits.

Comment: *Why* do you copy the stream contents to a byte array? If you do that there is no reason to return the *stream* with `File(..)`, just return the byte array eg `File(bytes...)`

Answer (score 22):

The stream was closed as soon as you exited the action method, or rather, the `using ( var ms = new MemoryStream() ) {` block.

You don't need to dispose the MemoryStream. The FileStreamResult object returned by `File(ms, "application/pdf", "Test.pdf");` will [dispose it after rendering](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/25eb50120eceb62fd24ab5404210428fcdf0c400/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/FileStreamResult.cs#L76). The code that actually sends the stream data is :

```
protected async override Task WriteFileAsync(HttpResponse response)
{
    var outputStream = response.Body;

    using (FileStream)
    {
        var bufferingFeature = response.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpBufferingFeature>();
        bufferingFeature?.DisableResponseBuffering();

        await FileStream.CopyToAsync(outputStream, BufferSize);
    }
}
```

You can replace this using block with :

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
try
{
     //..
     //From Igor's comment. FileStreamResult won't reset the stream position itself
     ms.Position=0;
     return File(ms, "application/pdf", "Test.pdf");
}
catch
{
    ms.Dispose();
    throw;
}
```

to ensure that the stream gets disposed if an error occurs.

**UPDATE**

As Igor mentioned, and as the source code shows, FileStreamResult won't reset the stream position. You'll have to set it to 0 before calling `return File(...)`

Comment: You probably also want to reset the position in the memory stream before passing it to File.  `ms.Position=0;`

Comment: Is there anything else that I could be missing? I'm going to paste my update code above

Comment: @SubparWebDev What do you mean? Did you encounter a different problem?

Answer (score 3):

The `PdfWriter` class may be closing your stream. Make sure to set the [`CloseStream`](http://www.afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/docs-itextsharp/html/19441909-0272-c9dd-7153-db7592c0ac24.htm) property to false.

Next you should *not* use `using` on the `MemoryStream` here, since the `FileStreamResult` action result will take care of disposing the stream after sending it off. Right now the stream is actually closed (by dispose) before the send takes place.

Also, you should seek the stream back to position 0 before sending off the file.

You can wrap the whole part in a `try...catch` however to dispose the stream in the case of an error (but the GC would eventually take care of it and `MemoryStream` if sully managed, so that's not mandatory).

Comment: `Document` is `iTextSharp.Text.Document`

Comment: The PdfWriter class may be closing your stream. Make sure to set the CloseStream property to false.  Most important line :)