# Xamarin.Forms itext7 - There is no associate PdfWriter for making indirects

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, itext, itext7

I am using itext7 to get the Stream of the file and fill in the form fields.

Here is my code:

```
using (MemoryStream outFile = new MemoryStream())
{
    var streamFile = await App.GraphClient.Me.Drive.Items[item.Id].Content.Request().GetAsync();

    using (PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(streamFile)))
    {

        PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf, true);

        IDictionary<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.GetFormFields();

        PdfFormField toSet;
        fields.TryGetValue("Full_Names", out toSet);
        toSet.SetValue(Customer_Name.Text);

        form.FlattenFields();
        pdf.Close();

    }
}
```

But I get an error on this line: `toSet.SetValue(Customer_Name.Text);` when trying to set the value, the error is:

> There is no associate PdfWriter for making indirects.

My question is what am I doing wrong and how do I fix this? I am getting the file from OneDrive using Microsoft Graph API. The IDictionary of fields is getting populated and the name of field I am trying to set the value for is accurate.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that you have dedicated `outFile` stream for the output result (the document with flattened fields) but you are not telling iText anything about that desired output destination.

`PdfDocument` has several constructors and the one you are using is `PdfDocument(PdfReader)` and it is dedicated for reading the document, not changing it (and setting a value is considered changing the document of course). So you should use `PdfDocument(PdfReader, PdfWriter)` constructor to provide the source document and the target destination to iText.

You should create your `PdfDocument` as follows:

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(streamFile), new PdfWriter(outFile))
```

At the end of the execution, your `outFile` stream will contain the bytes of the resultant document.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, but when I do that I get a new error saying "Can not access a closed Stream." what am I doing wrong now?

Comment: This is because the PdfReader closes the underlying stream automatically when being disposed of. The `using` statement does this automatically.For more details, you can check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934585/memorystream-cannot-access-a-closed-stream