# Getting ObjectDisposedException when IFormFile.CopyTo from another Context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an mvc core app that I am uploading and processing an .xlsx document. I want to make the initial POST call, create a new async task to do the processing work, while the post call returns me a GUID. I then periodically check if process is completed and return me results.

I am running into a dispose issue with 'FileBufferingReadStream' when doing IFormFile.CopyTo (also tried CopyToAsync).

Here is my controller that starts the new Task:

'''

```
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status409Conflict)]
[HttpPost]
[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 209715200)]
[RequestSizeLimit(209715200)]
[SetIdentity]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromForm] UploadRequestOptions value, [FromServices] 
IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
{
    var requestId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
   try
   {
       try
       {
           var caller = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Subject;
           value.UserId = caller.Name;

           /Attempt #1 of trying to fix dispose issue
           //cache the file and retrieve it in UploadBom method
           var file = value.File; 
           var cachedFile = new Tuple<string, IFormFile>(requestId, file);
           await _cache.SetAsync(requestId, cachedFile);

           Task.Run(async () =>
           {    
              using var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
              var upService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IBomUploadService>();
              await upService.UploadBom(value, requestId);
           });
    }
    catch (ValidationException ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, ex.ToString());
        return StatusCode(409, ex.Message);
    }

    return Ok(requestId);
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     _logger.LogError(ex, ex.ToString());
     return StatusCode(500, ex.Message);
 }
}
```

'''

and inside my Service I have this:

'''

```
    public async Task<int> UploadBom(UploadRequestOptions options, string requestId)
    {
      try
      {
        //Attempt #1 - retrieve cached file
        var cachedFile = await _cache.GetAsync<Tuple<string, IFormFile>>(requestId);
        var File = cachedFile.Item2;
    
         using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
         {
           //Here I get: : 'Cannot access a disposed object.                                 
           //Object name: 'FileBufferingReadStream'.'
           await File.CopyToAsync(memoryStream); 

           if (reader.LoadFile(memoryStream, "Tab1"))
           {
             result.Tab1Exists = true;
             result = await tabValidator.ValidateTabAsync(reader);
           }
           else
           {
             result.Tab1Exists = false;
           }
         }
       }
    }
```

'''

Here is the StackTrace I get:

'''

```
     at
     Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities
    .FileBufferingReadStream.ThrowIfDisposed()
     at 

     Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities
     .FileBufferingReadStream.set_Position(Int64 value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.ReferenceReadStream..ctor(Stream inner, 
   Int64 offset, Int64 length)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.FormFile.OpenReadStream()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.FormFile.CopyTo(Stream target)
   at Hamilton.Api.Services.BomUploadService.<UploadBom>d__6.MoveNext() in 
    C:\Development\Work Code\api\new-hamilton- 
    api\HamiltonAPI\Services\BomUploadService.cs:line 79
```

'''

Is there a way to initialize it or use the CopyTo in new Context? Is there better way to achieve this?

Comment: Please post the entire exception stack so we can see the details.

Comment: I have attached the StackTrace.

Comment: Please post the source code for `UploadRequestOptions`.

Comment: Playing with streams in this manner is prone to issues. You will need to make sure you keep the stream open. [Read this for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69184131/memorystream-closes-when-passing-it-as-a-parameter-to-another-method-with-a-loca). That being said, your code has a particularly strong smell. You should take a step back and review your architecture.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MemoryStream closes when passing it as a parameter to another method with a local function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69184131/memorystream-closes-when-passing-it-as-a-parameter-to-another-method-with-a-loca)

Comment: Thank you for the response and help, Juan. I am looking over the link you suggested and will have to test to see whether or not it is a solution. I will test it later this evening when I get back home.

Comment: Thank you, Charlieface. Your response was very helpful and the solution for me was to copy the file into a memoryStream before caching it. If you put that as an answer I will accept it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Task.Run` is your primary issue here: you are not awaiting it so the outer function is going to end before it finishes. So the stream gets disposed at that point.

Either await the resulting `Task`, or don't use it at all and call those functions directly using `await`.

Or if you really need to keep that code off the main thread then copy the file into a MemoryStream first before caching it.

Note also, that your cache system and `Task.Run` are prone to getting shut down without warning, because ASP.Net does not guarantee that background tasks will continue unless you use a `BackgroundService`.