# How to prevent closing stream when returning File result?

Tags: asp.net-core, stream, ironbarcode

I'm trying to return a file to browser, unfortunately I get an error:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.
> at System.IO.MemoryStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
> at System.IO.MemoryStream.ReadAsync(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

My controller action is:

```
public IActionResult DownloadBarcode(Guid barcodeId)
    {
        var currentUserId = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
        var barcode = _context.Barcodes.Find(barcodeId);
        
        var myBarcode = QRCodeWriter.CreateBarcode(barcode.Value);
        myBarcode.AddAnnotationTextBelowBarcode(barcode.Value);
        var stream = myBarcode.ToPdfStream();
        return File(stream, "application/pdf", $"etykieta{barcodeId}.pdf");
    }
```

The underlying 3rd party `ToPdfStream()` doesn't close the stream and sets `Position` to 0.

```
 public Stream ToPdfStream()
        {
            PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(generateUniqueDocumentIdentifiers: true);
            Bitmap innerBitmap = InnerBitmap;
            PdfPage pdfPage = pdfDocument.AddPage();
            pdfPage.Width = innerBitmap.Width;
            pdfPage.Height = innerBitmap.Height;
            pdfPage.TrimMargins.All = 0;
            DrawImage(XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdfPage), innerBitmap, 0, 0);
            using Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
            pdfDocument.Save(stream, closeStream: false);
            return stream;
        }
```

Comment: It's the `using` in `using Stream stream = new MemoryStream();` that is disposing the stream. Remove that `using` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can see [this awnser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10934585/14892988)...
Remove using in your ToPdfStream methode and use (using) in your DownloadBarcode action...
That do the same thing and your problem should be fixed.